# How to direct a text file to a C program using bash?

Tags: c++, linux, bash

I am doing "cat words | sign" (words is the text file and sign is the c program). However this seems to generate a infinite loop. Any idea how to solve this?

And what is the meaning of

```
sign < words | @sort > out
```

Below is the code for the c program.

```
int main(){
    char words[80];
    scanf("%s", words);
    printf(words);
    string_sort(words);
    printf(" ");
    printf(words);
    printf("\n");

    while ( words != ""){
            scanf("%s", words);
            printf("%s", words);
            string_sort(words);
            printf("%s", " ");
            printf("%s", words);
            printf("\n");
    }
 }
```

Comment: I think you should learn how strings work in C

Comment: i know...i've been using C++ since the first day I started leaning programming. but any idea how to resolve the infinite loop?

Comment: Putting two completely unrelated questions in a single question is no good and grounds for closing the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the program reaches EOF, `scanf()` leaves `words` unchanged, wich causes `words != ""` always be true.

Instead of testing `words`, you should test for `feof(stdin)`.

Comment: -1: Bad advice -- testing `feof(stdin)` is almost always wrong.  You want to check the return value of `scanf`; it will return 0 when it can't read a string.

Answer (score 0):

When you get to the end of the file, `scanf` will be unable to find a word and will return 0 (without changing the `words` array.)  You can call `scanf` directly in the while statement as `while(scanf("%s", words) == 1)`

Answer (score 0):

In bash, the `>` and `<` are used to redirect output to and input from files.  So `< words` means the program will read its stdin from `words` while `> out` means it will write its stdout to `out`.

`|` is used to connect two programs in a pipeline, with the output of the first program going to the input of the second.

So `sign < words | @sort > out` runs the two programs `sign` and `@sort`.  `sign` gets its input from the file `words` and send its output to the input of the `@sort` program, while the output of `@sort` goes to the file `out`

Answer (score 0):

This is always true for `char words[80];`:

```
words != ""
```

Because this is equivalent to `&words[0] == &""[0]`... You just compares pointers - one equal to begin of `words` and the other pointing to string literal `""`. They are always different.

You probably meant:

```
strcmp(words, "") != 0
```

Or just:

```
words[0] != 0
```